# Erro de login ao tentar subir projeto do Android Studio para o GitHub pela IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, github

Tentei subir meu projeto do Android Studio para o GitHub, mas está dando erro de login. Confirmei meu login e senha e estão corretos.  Alguém sabe como resolver? Procurei no Google e não achei a solução. A mensagem que aparece é a abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez não faça sentido, apenas por desencargo, já tentou utilizar o host `https://github.com' ? ( Com HTTPS://)

Comment: Sim, já tentei utilizar a url completa e, em vez do e-mail, utilizar somente o login. Em ambos os casos, a mensagem continuou a aparecer

Comment: Quais outras opções tem no Auth Type?

Comment: Sera que consegue trocar de HTTP para SSH?

Comment: Consegui, vou responder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via Token:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vá em `Developer Settings` e depois em `Personal Access Token`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em `Generate New Token` e crie o Token:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Copie o Token e cole-o na autenticação do Android Studio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo!!! Muito obrigada!